With unexpected strike, can I have 2 attacks of opportunity for the same enemy move?
So the ability  descriptions reads as follows:

Unexpected Strike (Ex)
Prerequisite: Barbarian 8
Benefit: The barbarian can make an attack of opportunity against a foe that moves into any square threatened by the barbarian, regardless of whether or not that movement would normally provoke an attack of opportunity.
Special: This power can only be used once per rage.

While the corresponding rule about multiple Aoo' reads as follows:

but if the same opponent provokes two attacks of opportunity from you, you could make two separate attacks of opportunity (since each one represents a different opportunity)

The text how generally a Aoo gets triggered reads:

Moving
Moving out of a threatened square usually provokes attacks of opportunity from threatening opponents.

So given this situation where

B= Babarian with unexpected strike and a means to do multiple Aoo
V= The victim and
T= A threatened field

TVT --> TTV
TBT --> TBT
TTT --> TTT
Since for one here the victim enters a field threatened by the babarian and in the same moment leaves a field that the babarian is threatening, from my understanding this would be 2 different opportunities and would lead the victim to receive 2 Aoo despite having only moved a single field.
Is this understanding correct?

There is precedent suggesting that you will only get one attack of opportunity (which I will refer to as AoO).
It's mentioned in the core rules for AoOs that there can only be one attack made when exiting multiple threatened squares:

Moving out of more than one square threatened by the same opponent in the same round doesn’t count as more than one opportunity for that opponent.

This by itself only rules on multiple AoOs in response to a single action if they have the same trigger condition. In order to handle multiple AoOs with different triggers, we end up needing to look at the official FAQ. On the entry for a Tiny creature entering another creature's space (here), it describes that entering another's space is a different trigger condition than leaving a threatened square (in the context that the former still provokes if using a 5-foot step). The entry then goes on to state that this doesn't lead to multiple AoOs:

This doesn’t mean that a Tiny or smaller creature entering a creature’s space and moving out of a threatened square with a move action provokes two attacks of opportunity from that creature, for the same reason that moving out of multiple of a creature’s threatened squares in the same move action doesn’t provoke two attacks of opportunity.

I wasn't able to find out exactly what the underlying reason for both these cases is, but it is reasonable to assume it prevents other instances of multiple AoOs by a single character against the same movement. Without a fortuitous weapon, of course.
